# set length of a 1d array with a variable

Tags: arrays, sas

I would like to set the length of an array depending on what value i obtain from reading a dataset:**number** which has one variable **num** with one numeric value. But I am getting an error message: saying that I cannot initiate the probs array. Can i get any suggestion on how to solve this issue? (I really don't want to hardcode the length of the probs array)

```
data test;
 if _n_=1 then do;
 set work.number;
 i =  num +1;
 end;

array probs{i} _temporary_ .....
```

Answer (score 3):

SAS Data step arrays can not be dynamically sized during step run-time.

One common approach is to place the computed number of rows of the data set into a macro variable before the data step.

I'm not sure what you are doing with `probs`.

- What values will be going into the array elements ?
- Do you need **all** *prob* data while iterating through each row of the data set ?
- Is a single result computed from the *probs* data ?

Example - Compute row count in a data *null* using `nobs` set option:

```
data _null_;
  if 0 then set work.number nobs=row_count;
  call symputx ('ROW_COUNT', row_count);
  stop;
run;

data test;
  array probs (&ROW_COUNT.) _temporary_;

  * something with probs[index] ;
  * maybe fill it ?
  do index = 1 by 1 until (last_row);
    set work.number;
    probs[index] = prob; * prob from ith row;
  end;

  * do some computation that a procedure isn't able to;
  …
  result_over_all_data = my_magic; * one result row from processing all prob;
  output;
  stop;
run;
```

Of course your actual use of the array will vary.

The many other ways to get row_count include `dictionary.table` views, sql `select count(*) into` and a variety of `ATTRN` invocations.